# Monster antiderivative for fun: $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{3e^{2x}\sin(x)+4e^{2x}\cos(x)}{-(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+\tan^2(x))}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

So I was bored, and decided to do antiderivatives for fun. After a while, I came up with this:$$\int\dfrac{3e^{2x}\sin(x)+4e^{2x}\cos(x)}{-(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+\tan^2(x))}dx$$which I thought that I might be able to do. Here is my attempt at doing so:

So first we notice that we can rewrite the the bottom of the fraction as$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+\tan^2(x)=1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$$and then noting that the derivative of the square of the secant function is $2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)$ so we have$$\sec^2(x)=\dfrac d{dx}(2\tan(x)\sec^2(x))$$and now to manipulate the top part. So recognizing that we need to get this into $\frac d{dx}(f(x)g(x))=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$ form, we have$$3e^{2x}\sin(x)+4e^{2x}\cos(x)=4e^{2x}\sin(x)-e^{2x}\sin(x)+2e^{2x}\cos(x)+2e^{2x}\cos(x)\\=\dfrac d{dx}(2e^{2x}\sin(x)+e^{2x}\cos(x))$$so now the integral is just$$-\int\dfrac{\frac d{dx}(2e^{2x}\sin(x)+e^{2x}\cos(x))}{\frac d{dx}(2\tan(x)\sec^2(x))}dx$$And since I know that$$\dfrac d{dx}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac{\frac d{dx}f(x)}{\frac d{dx}g(x)}$$because of L'Hôpital's Rule, we have our antiderivative to be$$\dfrac{-(2e^{2x}\sin(x)+e^{2x}\cos(x))}{2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)}+c$$or just$$-e^{2x}\sin(x)\cos^2(x)\cot(x)-0.5e^{2x}\cos^3(x)\cot(x)+c$$

---

### My question

---

Did I calculate the antiderivative correctly, or what could I do to caculate the antiderivative?

Comment: How $\sec^2(x)=\dfrac d{dx}(2\tan(x)\sec^2(x))$ ?

Comment: Also, how did the $\log$ disappear from the title?

Comment: L hopital's rule is only applicable for limit's, and D(f(x)/g(x)) where D is first derivative is not equal to what you wrote

Comment: @NinadMunshi I must've accidentally put it there by accident :\

Comment: @CrSb0001 in the title there's log in the denominator, whereas in the body no. What's the right integrand?

Comment: @SineoftheTime $\int\frac{3e^{2x}\sin(x)+4e^{2x}\cos(x)}{-(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+\tan^2(x)}dx$, I'll just fix the title to avoid any more confusion

Comment: So many paranthesises but still one is missing...

Comment: Don’t mix the chain rule and the L’Hospital Rule like $\dfrac d{dx}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\ne\dfrac{\frac d{dx}f(x)}{\frac d{dx}g(x)}$

Comment: @Lai is right. It is however true that $df(x)/dg(x)=f^\prime/g^\prime$

Comment: You should use the quotient rule to deal with d/dx(f/g).

Comment: Quotient Rule for derivative of a quotient of two functions of $x, f $and $g$,$\frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)=\frac{g f^{\prime}-f g^{\prime}}{g^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Without any integration by parts.*

After the simplification of the denominator
$$I=-\int e^{2 x} \cos ^2(x) (3 \sin (x)+4 \cos (x))\,dx$$

Linearizing the powers
$$I=-\int e^{2x} \left(\frac{3 }{4}\sin (x)+\frac{3}{4} \sin (3 x)+3 \cos(x)+\cos (3 x)\right)\,dx$$ Use Euler representation of the sine and cosine functions to just face four exponentials with complex arguments which are more than simple to integrate.

Taking the real part of the result
$$I=-\frac{1}{260} e^{2 x} (234 \sin (x)+90 \sin (3 x)+273 \cos (x)-5  \cos (3 x))$$

Answer (score 3):

You calculated the denominator as $-\sec^2x$. So your monster integral is
$$\int(-3e^{2x}\sin x\cos^2x-4e^{2x}\cos^3x)dx=\int e^{2x}(\cos^3x)'dx-4\int e^{2x}\cos^3xdx$$
By integration by parts for the first integral we have
$$e^{2x}\cos^3x-6\int e^{2x}\cos^3xdx.$$
That is where I am disappointed. I expected cancellation.
If you change $+4$ to $-2$, then the answer would be $e^{2x}\cos^3x.$

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance but I guess Leibovici found the full result. Isn't the result important but not the process?

Comment: Very nice attitude ! Bé sure that I appreciate. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{3 e^{2 x} \sin x+4 e^{2 x} \cos x}{-\left(\sin ^2 x+\cos ^2 x+\tan ^2 x\right)} d x = & -\int \frac{3 e^{2 x} \sin x+4 e^{2 x} \cos x}{\sec ^2 x} d x \\
= & \int\left(-3e^{2 x} \sin x \cos ^2 x-4 e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x\right) d x \\
= & \int e^{2 x} d\left(\cos ^3 x\right)-4 \int e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x d x \\
= & e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x-2 \int e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x d x-4 \int e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x d x \\
= & e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x-6\int e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x d x
\end{aligned}
$$
For the last integral, we can use the formula: $\cos 3 x=4 \cos ^3 x-3 \cos x$ and get
$$
\int e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x d x  =\frac{1}{4}\left[\int e^{2 x} \cos 3 x d x+3 \int e^{2 x} \cos x d x\right]
$$
Using integration by parts twice, we get a formula
$$
\int e^{a x} \cos b x d x=\frac{e^{a x}}{a^2+b^2}(a \cos b x+b \sin b x)
$$
and obtain
$$
\int e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x d x  =\frac{e^{2 x}}{260}\left( 15 \sin 3 x+10 \cos 3 x+39 \sin x+78 \cos x\right)
$$
Hence we can conclude that
$$\boxed{\quad  \int \frac{3 e^{2 x} \sin x+4 e^{2 x} \cos x}{-\left(\sin ^2 x+\cos ^2 x+\tan ^2 x\right)} d x \\= e^{2 x} \cos ^3 x - \frac{3e^{2x}}{130}\left( 15 \sin 3 x+10 \cos 3 x+39 \sin x+78 \cos x\right) +C}$$

Comment: İs there a sign mistake at the start? I got $-6$ as the coefficient of the second part.

Comment: Bob, thank you very much for pointing out my error.